# MetaMask conflicting with Coinbase wallet

Tags: ethereum, web3js, metamask, coinbase-api

I am trying to connect to the metamask from my dapp. following the docs: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html#connecting-to-metamask

but when I call `eth_requestAccounts` method it's opening coinbase popup as well.

how to work around this? any suggestions?

```
ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Issue being that you have more than one provider installed, if you want to only target MetaMask you need to pick that provider alone.

```
// Find MetaMask Provider

const provider = window.ethereum.providers.find((provider) => provider.isMetaMask);
provider.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
```

You can also try using metamask provider detector but it didn't work for me.
https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#ethereum-provider-api

Comment: This isn't working for me on the chrome as `window.ethereum.providers` is `undefined`. Any other solution?

Comment: @UsmanPervaiz Kindly check if you have any ethereum provider (browser extension like metamask) installed in your browser, this should even work if you type it in your browser console.

Comment: Yes, I had installed the meta mask extension on the chrome. But I have figured out the issue. We get `window.ethereum.providers` when `Coinbase wallet extension` is installed in the chrome.
I was actually trying to resolve the conflict between Metamask and Math Wallet.
Thanks for the support :)

Comment: yeah that package is pretty useless. Even if you pass mustBeMetaMask option to it still both will show up

Answer (score 1):

Easily, you can switch providers (similar other wallets):

```
let provider;
    switch (providerName) {
        case ConnectorName.CoinbaseWallet:
            provider = ethereum.providers.find(({ isCoinbaseWallet }: any) => isCoinbaseWallet);
            break;
        case ConnectorName.Injected:
            provider = ethereum.providers.find(({ isMetaMask }: any) => isMetaMask);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (provider) {
        ethereum.setSelectedProvider(provider);
    }
```